# Gegenteil von Apotheose?

Tags: single-word-request, antonym

[Apotheose](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apotheose) = Erhebung eines Menschen zu einem Gott

What is the opposite, where a god would become mortal? / Was ist das Gegenteil, wenn also ein Gott sterblich würde?

Comment: Degradierung ;p

Comment: Hmm, ich kenne Beispiele von Göttern, die gestorben sind, aber die sind nicht, soweit ich weiß, erstmal 'sterblich geworden'.  (Jesus zählt nicht, da er dann doch unsterblich war.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the religious context, I would use [Menschwerdung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menschwerdung_Gottes), *Fleischwerdung* or *Inkarnation*, the last of which has Latin roots.

Comment: Menschwerdung itself without any explanation doesn't imply that one was a former god (who now has become a human), so it's no perfect fit. I don't think one will find something fitting in christian mythology, because there is only one god... The other two also seem to mean something slightly different.

Comment: @sinned It's the best fit you are likely to get. Words can have different meanings in different contexts, which is why I added "in the religious context". Also, as the WP article I linked states, there is only one god in Chrisitanity, but that one god is composed of *The Holy Trinity* of Father, Son, and Holy Spirit; the Son is that part of God that became a human being, i.e. who was *incarnated*, literally translated *made into flesh*.

Comment: Christliche Menschen glauben an die Menschwerdung eines Gottes, die aber nicht eine Abwertung bedeutet bzw. die Aufgabe der göttlichen Natur - das ist quasi ein Hybrid. Damit taugt es nicht als Gegenteil.

Answer (score 2):

Eine Antwort aus einem anderen Blickwinkel wäre nietzscheanisch: Götter werden sterblich (und sterben ggf. schließlich), wenn sie von den Menschen nicht mehr fortwährend erschaffen werden. Aus einer konstruktivistischen Sicht also, im Gegensatz zu der in der Frage implizierten monotheistisch Religiösen (nämlich dass *ein* Gott sei).

*Götzendämmerung*, oder auch das "Original" *Götterdämmerung*, wären somit Kandidaten eines *doppelten* (Gott wird sterblich *und* Perspektive wird menschlich), allerdings eher philosophischen als sprachlichen Gegenteils von *Apotheose*.

Answer (score 1):

Der von dir zur Diskussion gestellte Vorgang ist aus rein logischen Gründen nicht möglich:

Ein Wesen, egal ob Gott oder etwas anderes, kann entweder sterblich oder unsterblich sein, aber nicht beides zugleich. Wenn ein Wesen auf irgendeine Weise unsterblich geworden ist, kann es laut Definition niemals sterben. "Niemals" bedeutet: "Nie und nimmer, unter gar keinen Umständen, egal was passiert". Ein unsterbliches Wesen überlebt also alles was ihm im Lauf seines unendlich langen Lebens passiert.

Sterblich zu sein bedeutet die Fähigkeit zu haben, irgendwann in der Zukunft (die auch eine sehr ferne Zukunft sein kann) zu sterben. Ein Sterblicher ist aber nicht gezwungen, von dieser Fähigkeit tatsächlich Gebrauch zu machen. Auch jemand der sterben könnte wäre also in der Lage beliebig lange zu leben. Das könnte für uns Menschen eintreten, wenn wir z.B. durch ausgereifte Technologie in der Lage sein werden verbrauchte Organe durch frische zu ersetzen. Dann würden uns Gift oder ein Verkehrsunfall nach wie vor töten können, aber wer sich gesund ernährt und in einer sicheren Umgebung bleibt, kann dann beliebig alt werden, vielleicht sogar viele Millionen Jahre oder noch viel mehr.

Wenn nun ein wirklich "unsterbliches" Wesen die Fähigkeit hätte sterblich zu werden, würde das bedeuten, dass es für dieses Wesen einen Umstand (nämlich die Erlangung der Sterblichkeit) gibt, der in weiterer Folge zum Tod führen könnte. Genau dieses Vorhandensein solcher möglicher Umstände ist aber für unsterbliche Wesen ausgeschossen.

Fazit:
Ein Wesen, das sterblich werden könnte ist nicht unsterblich.

Comment: "Oh dear," says God, "I hadn't thought of that," and promptly disappears in a puff of logic.

Comment: Nach derselben Logik kann ein Feuer nie "außer Kontrolle geraten".

Comment: Oder ein roter Gegenstand nie blau werden.

Comment: Wer sich auf Götter einlässt entbindet sich ja nun selbst von Logik und Empirie - wieso sollte es aber nicht möglich sein auf Privilegien freiwillig zu verzichten? Einem Abgeordneten kann auch die Immunität entzogen werden - das bedeutet nicht, dass er per se nicht immun wäre. Ich würde im Gegenteil sagen, dass etwas, was nicht sterblich werden kann, auch nicht unsterblich sein kann - etwa ein Stein.

Comment: Der Bub hat 'ne einfache Frage gestellt und ihr macht daraus eine philosphische Diskussion. Schämt ihr euch gar nicht?

Comment: Nein, warum schämen? Ich bin schon groß, ich darf das schon.

Comment: Das ist auschließlich ein Beitrag zur Diskussion der Sachfrage, hier soll aber eine Sprachfrage diskutiert werden. Es gibt durchaus auch sprachliche Bezeichnungen für nichtexistierende und auch für unmögliche Dinge. Daher ist die Sachdiskussion hier überhaupt fehl am Platze. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: Im Übrigen könnte "Unsterblichkeit" eine zeitgebundene Eigenschaft sein, so wie "Jugend": Eine Göttin könnte zu einer bestimmten Zeit unsterblich sein, und bspw. aus dem Fenster fallen, oder von Kugeln durchbohrt werden ohne zu sterben. Sie könnte diese Eigenschaft später wieder verlieren, und wäre dann sterblich.  Das Argument in der Sachfrage ist also auch nicht korrekt. Aber das gehört eigentlich gar nicht hierher.